# What is a good project for amatuer PCB designers?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, pcb-design

I'm new to PCB designing, and I was wondering what are good first design challenges? I've done a few circuits thus far, and I want to expand my knowledge by making my own etched circuit boards. I already know basic design principle and circuit theory.
What project, that focuses on PCB design, would be of the most educational value for me as a beginner?

Comment: LED Drivers / H-Bridges seem to be all the rage now a days =-D

Comment: I would say build projects that interest you. Learning will naturally come over time as things don't work as you expect

Comment: A while ago, I used to do a PCB design workshop for beginners.  The [standard homework project](http://prolifictec.com/pcbclass/index.html) was a motor driver based on L298.  It had just enough mechanical constraints to make the PCB layout just a little bit challenging.  Students could also do their own designs if they fit the [criteria](http://prolifictec.com/pcbclass/PCB%20class%20project%20RFP.pdf).  The workshop had 2 meetings and about 6 to 8 hours of class and lab over the course of 2 or 3 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL; DR - PRACTICE and get your design reviewed by someone who is in the industry for long. That's how you will improve.

I'll share my story. I'm still amateur at PCB design; although have fared well in past year.

I started in 2009 when i was in my 9th grade. I desperately wanted a MP3 player. My father didn't want to throw money on expensive iPods(ipods were the new cool at that time). So I took it to myself; built one myself. Of course with help. I didn't have the technical know-how of any design. I read books like crazy. Couldn't comprehend a word.

In this process; because i was short on money; I decided to fabricate a PCB myself. I discovered options like toner transfer that is possible at home. Eventually, now, after 7 years i can manufacture good pcbs for initial prototyping.

I got the PIC18F series programmed by someone who was 500 miles away. I was 15 at that time.

Completed this project when I completed my 12th grade. About 3 years.

TECHNICAL COMPETENCE = ZERO.

But, it worked. 
I started my Bachelors in Electronics and made amendments to the existing design. PCB Designs got better and progressed as time passed.  In  the final year of my bachelors, I am pushing good designs which find their place in industrial components. From single layer to six layer boards with RF Components.  I've picked up skills from forums, tutorials, electronics.stackexchange. Olin Sir had amazing answers. But one thing remained common, PRACTICE and learning from mistakes. There's no shortcut.

Comment: how many PCBs did you go through before you got 'the right one'?

Comment: if you are asking PCB design iterations; it took me a year to get it right and reviewed by my father ( he's an electronics engineer). In that process, at least manufactured 12-13 pieces of PCB. All of them never worked.

Comment: is it a coincidence that he's an electronics engineer, and didn't want to put money into an ipod? I think not. haha!

Comment: Maybe. Father's denial helped me to push myself more. Go design one. Ask questions. That's how you learn. And I hope this answers your question.